# Passar variável Javascript para variável de Escopo Global em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, escopo-de-variáveis

Como posso passar uma variável em Javascript/Jquery para uma variável de Escopo Global em PHP? recentemente precisei que uma variável de escopo global em PHP recebesse um valor javascript, essa variável seria utilizada depois em outras páginas, cheguei a usar o Ajax e enviar a variável via POST para uma página php e depois incluir o resultado via append  na página principal, só que eu precisaria que a variável PHP que recebeu o valor ficasse disponível globalmente para ser usada em outras confirmações e páginas.
Pra contornar o problema cheguei a passar o valor via Cookie com Jquery, só que essa não me parece ser a maneira correta de se fazer isso. o código a baixo é a tentativa de utilizar o Ajax para tentar criar a variável de escopo global em PHP

## index.php

```
<script>
    $(window).ready(function(){
    var variavel = "valor a ser passado para variavel de escopo global php";

       $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "script.php",
       data: { nome: variavel }
    })
      .done(function( data ){
           // resposta do servidor
           $("#conteudo").append(data)       
    });
    });
</script>

<div id='conteudo'></div>
```

## script.php

Recebe o valor Post JS e é adicionada via append na página principal

```php
if( isset($_POST['nome'])){

    $valor = $_POST['nome'];

    $varTeste = json_encode($valor);

    $varTeste; // variável que deveria ficar disponível globalmente

    echo $varTeste;

}
```

Comment: Já estudou sessões do PHP?

Comment: Realmente não tinha me passado pela cabeça utilizar sessões, e agora que vc falou ficou obvio que era o que eu devia ter usado, obrigado pela resposta, daqui a pouco atualizo com o trechinho do código que resolve o problema para alguma outra alma perdida rsrrsr, vlw msm Anderson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o caso de mais alguém ter o mesmo problema a solução realmente foi armazenar em uma sessão php, no caso eu utilizei pra armazenar o tamanho da tela do usuário pegando via Jquery e enviando via post por Ajax

na página script.php acrescentei

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["screenWidth"];
```

Depois quando for utilizar basta iniciar a sessão e armazenar em uma variável
no meu caso na página index.php

```
session_start();
$screenWidth = $_SESSION["screenWidth"];
echo $screenWidth;
```

Também removi o append já que eu não tinha necessidade de trazer um resultado tratado e tudo o que precisava era armazenar somente o valor da variável.

```
   $("#conteudo").append(data); // parte desnecessária removida
```